# Why was my question closed as off topic? If that was done correctly, on which SE site should I ask?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question at [How can I get distcc compilation to work in a distributed way via a systemd service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65330601/how-can-i-get-distcc-compilation-to-work-in-a-distributed-way-via-a-systemd-serv) was closed as off topic with the note "We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow."

Quoting from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
> software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

And also:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
> for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
> for programming

Distcc is a distributed compilation tool. It is used primarily for programming. So why was my question closed?

Also, if the question truly should have been closed, where should I ask?

Comment: No, it does not, but perhaps I should rephrase the title of the question as to not include "Ubuntu". It's relevant to any linux system that uses systemd and distcc.

Comment: this seems to have something to do with your configuration and is so pfftopic in SO as the link provided explained

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem you're having isn't just a network/setup/configuration issue. That doesn't smell like an actual programming problem.

Comment: Ok, let me be very clear about this. It's most likely not about configuration of systemd (since I've done virtually nothing to change that) and most likely about configuration of distcc itself.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to ask on AskUbuntu and see how it goes... If I get the same kind of response there, I'll get back to this thread.

Comment: I agree with your logic and disagree with the close voters. I think it might be a better fit for Unix&Linux SE or AskUbuntu SE, but I would argue it's not off-topic for SO since it's about compiling code. I've voted to reopen, we'll see what the community decides.

Comment: @JaredSmith your argument is then: it is a tool often used by software developers/engineers to accomplish a specific programming task?

Comment: @rene a C++ compiler? Yes.

Comment: BTW, read the configuration guide https://wiki.debian.org/Distcc

Comment: @JaredSmith no, it's not a C++ compiler. It calls the c++ installed compiler but by itself it compiles nothing. From the homepage "distcc is not itself a compiler, but rather a front-end to the GNU C/C++ compiler (gcc) and LLVM compiler (clang)." https://distcc.github.io/

Comment: @Braiam I'm sure that's a valuable distinction in many contexts. I don't feel this is one of them: at the end of the day we're still talking about a code-related tool, and it's still IMO on-topic on stack overflow.

Comment: @JaredSmith aren't all tools code related tools? You need to draw a line, otherwise every OS question is on topic on SO because programmers have to use them. This line I set it as "is X material to the question asked?" and the answer is a rotund no. The system used (Debian) and how it manages start up scripts (using /etc/default) are the important bits here. LDAP, avahi, deluge, openvpn, etc. also present these same issues and solutions and most of them aren't "code-related tool".

Comment: @JaredSmith also, OP went to argue with me that the issue resided somewhere else, until I pressed it enough so that it share the critical information in their question. Would you be able to do the same if this was actually just a "code related tool" and not a system orchestration service?

Comment: @Braiam it is, admittedly, a bit of an edge case. You (and apparently at least two others?) came down on one side, other people came down on another. And I get that you have to draw a line, and I stated in my comment that it would be a better fit for some other stacks. But I *still* think it's on topic, although I respect that reasonable people could disagree.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If we assume distcc is a C++ compiler that is a tool often used by a software engineer to accomplish a programming task, then it is on-topic.

It becomes a bit vague when such questions are about the installation of tools used by software developers. Installation / setup configuration issues often have a wide range of fail cases and having all of them in a Q/A format is maybe useful for the OP but if it will help many visitors to comes remains to be seen.

In the case of distcc, I take the position that questions about setup and configuration are on-topic, given that the toolstack is so tightly bound to software development and it is unlikely you'll find experts on that tool elsewhere. That said, I do expect questions to be strictly about the tool and not about underlying infrastructure, OS and/or services. The onus is on the asker to provide the evidence that those root causes for problems are ruled out.

My judgement call here was that the issue is with distcc and therefore your question is on-topic. I've voted to re-open the question.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. Read the first and second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @Braiam, with all due respect, I disagree with you. You argue that just because the problem and solution require some networking knowledge, the question is not related to programming and is somehow a bad fit for the StackOverflow Q/A website. The opposing side (myself included) is arguing that distcc is a tool used and set up for use by programmers, so it is both a good fit to be answers by those who tread that path before me -- mostly, programmers -- and the potential solution is valuable for those who will use distcc in the same context -- mostly programmers.

Comment: @GregKramida that's unrelated. Just because you use Windows while programming doesn't make any question about windows a programming question. Is a matter of topically. You go at it thinking that is related to programming just because you are a programmer. Programmers face many issues, not all of them should be asked on SO. Anyways, your question as asked was lacking information needed for answering (the distcc file) and that was enough to get it closed first, the mistake here was that close voters didn't knew enough about the topic and closed it as off topic.

Comment: @rene While I broadly agree with your answer, from https://github.com/distcc/distcc "distcc is not itself a compiler". Pedantry maybe, but important I believe.

Comment: Not all questions related to tools used by programmers are automatically on-topic. Things like "*How do I select a word in the terminal output of my compiler*", "*How to add my favourite IDE to the task bar*" or "*How to start an editor in a remote desktop session*" are absolutely off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 15):

I disagree with others' claim that the question was off-topic for Stack Overflow. As you said here, this is a tool primarily used by programmers, which makes it *de facto* on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Whether it might get a better answer somewhere else, or who is most qualified to answer it, are both irrelevant when it comes to determining the topicality of a question. What is even *more* irrelevant to the topicality of a question is its answer. The topicality of a question is judged *prima facie*, not after seeing how it was solved and judging what specific type of expertise was required to arrive at that solution.

*That said*, given the controversy, and the fact that your question was flagged by a user with significant experience and esteem on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com), I have migrated it there. I think we can all agree that it is on-topic for Unix & Linux, and I think that's probably the best place for you to get a good answer. (I'd rather your question find a home and get a good answer than we have good fodder for a debate on Meta…)

Please don't take my decision to migrate the question to Unix & Linux as evidence that I think the question was unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Similar questions are still on-topic here.

(And, aside from all else, please do not cross-post on multiple Stack Exchange sites.)

Comment: Thanks, I've deleted the question from AskUbuntu at this point, sorry about cross-posting.

Comment: Not all questions related to tools used by programmers are automatically on-topic. Things like "*How do I select a word in the terminal output of my compiler*", "*How to add my favourite IDE to the task bar*" or "*How to start an editor in a remote desktop session*" are absolutely off-topic on StackOverflow. It's not necessary to know the answer to determine the topicality. What matters is whether programmer knowledge is required to answer.

Comment: @Bergi: [Straw Man Argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).

Comment: @Bergi No, it really doesn't matter at all whether programmer knowledge is required to answer. It matters merely what tools you are using. Your examples are poorly chosen, however. "My favorite IDE" is too open-ended, but a question about launching Visual Studio Code in a remote desktop session is definitely on-topic here, like it or not. Visual Studio Code is a tool commonly used by programmers. The Help Center is extremely clear here.

Comment: @CodyGray I disagree. It's like boat programming - just being used by programmers is not enough. Launching vscode in a rdp session is the same as launching *any other program* in that session. You can remove "vscode" from the question, the answer stays the same. It's a question about rdp, which should be asked on SU not SO.

Answer (score 8):

I concur with the hivemind on this one: Greg's question was definitely on-topic for Stack Overflow.

As a different example, consider a hypothetical question about an issue with the Visual Studio IDE caused by a Microsoft Windows Registry tweak. Should we push that question to a hypothetical Windows-specific Stack Exchange site?

I don't think so: while it's true that programming knowledge isn't required to answer the question, it's not a question that would generally be asked outside of the *context* of programming, and therefore it absolutely is on topic here. The same applies to Greg's question.

Further, if I had the same question Greg has, I would definitely ask it here first. The fact that it's caused by a misconfiguration is superseded by the fact that it falls within the scope for programming.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as demostrated, I, a non-distcc expert nor programmer, answered your question. That's not programming. Since the parameters reside on `/etc/default` which "contains some parameters that the **end user or administrator** is likely to change, rather than embedding the values in the actual boot scripts. In this way, changes will persist even if you upgrade the package and the boot script is replaced."

It doesn't matter that your software is "used by programmers". A system administrator is the knowledge you need to actually answer the issue. That's why, just because you find a problem while programming, doesn't automatically make the question about said issue a programming question. This question reads as "my service doesn't listen on a port, why?" which requires checking from the client (are we on the same network), passing through every middlebox (firewalls and whatnot), and to the system network sockets (ie. is even the service configured to listen? Is it allowed to?).

Those steps are all not programming and things you have to clear out first. Your system administrator should be able to help you out figure it out, which is something I did.

BTW, this question [was crossposted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1300847/169736), and it's being closed as non-reproducible.

Comment: On another note, systemd services are more often than not shipping with very restrictive cgroups that allow only network access on the local device. As such, you must check out every configuration knob and log to find where the issue lies.

Comment: I appreciate your taking the time to answer, and all of this is fine, except I'm working from home and setting up my compilation system on several machines to speed it up, there is no "system administrator" to speak of except yours truly, so I'm just trying to get this tool to work for me with my coding. Again, this is about a tool that is used exclusively for programming, hence it seems relevant to SO, even if the problem lies with configuration. SO contains a myriad of questions about how to configure IDEs and such (upvoted as well), so I don't see how this is any different conceptually.

Comment: I'll investigate the cgroups issue, thank you for that lead as well.

Comment: @GregKramida debian wiki has the answer to what I believe to be your problem. Make sure that you follow it. https://wiki.debian.org/Distcc

Comment: I have already configured `/etc/default/distcc` and `$HOME/.distcc/hosts` in agreement with that guide, I'm not sure what else can be done about that.

Comment: @GregKramida did you check ALLOWEDNETS and LISTENER?

Comment: yes, I did all of that apriori. I started with this. These settings actually control the way the distcc daemon is launched, i.e. in the original question, service status, the things that go after --allow and --listen

Comment: @GregKramida no, you don't show that on your question. You should include the content of distcc file.

Comment: it follows logically from "The launcher line seems to correspond to what I do manually (i.e. seems like I've configured /etc/default/distcc correctly)", I can also add "if I change contents of /etc/default/distcc the launcher line also changes accordingly". I do want to avoid including the entire configuration file in the original post because I know that visually-long question tend to attract less attention because they may seem overwhelming / tedious to read.

Comment: @GregKramida no, you must include all the information. You can be mistaken or misreading. That's why you should include it.

Comment: ok, I'll copy/paste the file.

Comment: "*I, a non-distcc expert nor programmer, answered your question. That's not programming*" I'm not sure what the argument is here, but as phrased it sounds like a question is not a programming question if it can be answered by someone who isn't an expert, which is... well... wrong.

Comment: @TylerH no, it's actually correct. Because you, a would presume programmer, aren't able to evaluate the question correctly enough _to answer it_. I do, and that's enough to establish the kind of knowledge to do a sensible evaluation on the topicality of a question. You need to know what's being asked about, to understand whenever or not it is on topic. The other answer fails to do this and just go by the basic understanding that the service is capable of compiling C++, when the problem is that it is a service and it's misconfigured.

Comment: @Braiam So your argument is that you claim to not be a programmer and yet are able to answer a question on a programming Q&A site? Just want to get this straight. If that is correct, how do you account for your 40 answers and 12 questions on said site?

Comment: @TylerH because I don't call myself a programmer, I'm someone that dabbles in coding. An aficionado. The knowledge I have is something that no one would call themselves a programmer, but more of a jack of all trades. Someone which knowledge is only on coding, would be able to call themselves a programmer. Sadly, said knowledge isn't even relevant here.

Comment: @Braiam I think the distinction there is academic at best. You write code, that makes you a programmer. Perhaps not by vocation or trade, but the site is not just for professional programmers, but also enthusiasts (something of a synonym for 'aficionado'). Also, programmers also have knowledge of other things and systems (moreso than most, I'd argue, by the nature of programmers needing to understand systems in order to write effective code).

Comment: @TylerH yet, programmers are failing at correctly identifying the topic with enough accuracy to know which site it should be asked upon. I knew that OP was lacking information from the get go (see par. 2 last sentence) because I evaluated the question as a system administrator would (specifically about Debian). This issue isn't even exclusive to the "tool commonly used by programmers" since there are several services that would present the same issue and be solved using the same methodology: verify from client to server where the connection fails.

Comment: _"I, a non-distcc expert nor programmer, answered your question"_ -- did that answer get deleted later then? I'm asking because I can't see any answers on that question. (I suppose the answer would have to have been deleted before the question was migrated to unix.SE, because I would see a deleted answer there.)